# Safe way to limit GPIO output time

Tags: gpio

I'm trying to figure out a fail-safe way to provide an output on GPIO pin of the Pi that would not be vulnerable to my (possibly) buggy code crashes. Is there a surefire way to do so?

Scenario: I need to put GPIO pin to HIGH for up to 30 seconds, while I observe sensor data to make a determination of what happens. If I observe desired conditions are met earlier, I need to pull pin LOW. But if my code crashes, I don't want the pin to remain HIGH for an hour or a day while I figure out that my code crashed.

Short of building a separate circuit (something like 555 timer), is there a way to do this with SoC instructions that would continue in a case of a crash?

PS: Just to clarify, the kind of crash I'm talking about is not Raspberry Pi crash, it's my application crash. Pi will continue idling, while my python process terminates unexpectedly.

Comment: use a watchdog timer

Answer (score 2):

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) will probably let you do what you want using waves.

The following command line example uses [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) to set GPIO 4 high for 7 seconds.

```
pigs m 4 w                    # set GPIO 4 to mode output
pigs wvag 16 0 7000000 0 16 0 # wave to switch GPIO 4 high for 7 seconds, then off
pigs wvcre                    # create wave (should return wave 0)

pigs wvtx 0                   # transmit wave 0
```

You can do the same using the [pigpio Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html).  Even if the script crashes the GPIO will be switched off at the conclusion of the wave.